# NullReferenceException when executing Publish Code Coverage Results - Azure devops

Tags: azure, unit-testing, azure-devops, code-coverage

Hi I'm new to azure devOps and Asp.net. I'm trying to implement Code Coverage in Azure devOps to a simple Console App. getting following error when I'm trying to implement that.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MECWr.png)

```
**Starting: PublishCodeCoverageResults
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish code coverage results v2
Description  : Publish any of the code coverage results from a build
Version      : 2.218.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results
==============================================================================
Found 1 result(s) matching pattern: **CalculatorApp.nUnit.Test/TestResults/Coverage/*coverage.cobertura.xml
D:\a\1\s\CalculatorApp.nUnit.Test\TestResults\Coverage\coverage.cobertura.xml
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" D:\a\_tasks\PublishCodeCoverageResults_2a7ebc54-c13e-490e-81a5-d7561ab7cd97\2.218.0\node_modules\coveragepublisher\CoveragePublisher\CoveragePublisher.Console.dll "D:\a\1\s\CalculatorApp.nUnit.Test\TestResults\Coverage\coverage.cobertura.xml" --reportDirectory D:\a\_temp\6c5c8a87-1929-4a83-a0c5-183961a9535a
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.EnvironmentProvider.get_ExecutableExtensions()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.EnvironmentProvider.GetCommandPathFromRootPath(String rootPath, String commandName, String[] extensions)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.CommandFactory.AbstractPathBasedCommandResolver.Resolve(CommandResolverArguments commandResolverArguments)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.CommandFactory.CompositeCommandResolver.Resolve(CommandResolverArguments commandResolverArguments)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.CommandFactory.CommandFactoryUsingResolver.Create(ICommandResolverPolicy commandResolverPolicy, String commandName, IEnumerable`1 args, NuGetFramework framework, String configuration, String outputPath, String applicationName)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, TimeSpan startupTime, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)**
```

This is my yaml

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/CalculatorApp.nUnit.Test/*.csproj'
    publishTestResults: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) /p:CollectCoverage=true  /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:CoverletOutput=./TestResults/Coverage/ '


- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
  inputs:    
    summaryFileLocation: '**CalculatorApp.nUnit.Test/TestResults/Coverage/*coverage.cobertura.xml'
```

**Test**:

[image]

I've tried a lot of stuff. I can't figure out why I'm getting this NullRefereneException.

Comment: Found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change arguments in test task.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/CalculatorApp.nUnit.Test/*.csproj'
    publishTestResults: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)   --collect "Code coverage" '
```

remove PublishCodeCoverageResults@2

```
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
  inputs:    
    summaryFileLocation: '**CalculatorApp.nUnit.Test/TestResults/Coverage/*coverage.cobertura.xml'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).